# How to access Amazon EC2 instance from Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: networking, 13.10, ssh, dns, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 (Windows) instance which has been created for me and I have public DNS, public IP and the public key.

I would like to RDP to this instance from Ubuntu 13.10. I have recently downloaded rDesktop but don't know how to connect to EC2 instance through it.

Would someone please be able to lay down step-by-step instructions on how to do it? I am totally new to Linux.

In rDesktop, when I choose the option 'RDP' there are 3 tabs displayed - Basic, Advanced and SSH with various options in them.

I am a little confused on how to go ahead with the things I have with me (public DNS, public IP and the public key).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to connect to ec2 instance 
you just need a .pem key (Public key)  username and public dns

for example sudo ssh -i "public key" username@public dns

sudo ssh -i "xyz.pem" ubuntu@ec2-public-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com

after that select yes

That it now You can connect to EC2 instance through terminal.